# How to change labels font size in Holoviews chord diagram?

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, data-science, holoviews, chord-diagram

I'm trying to draw a chord diagram using HoloViews, and it seems to work fine, but I can't figure how to change labels font size. I tried changing fontscale value but it seems to have no effects on labels.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import dim, opts
hv.extension('bokeh')


chord = hv.Chord(temp) # temp is a pandas dataframe with cloumns=["from","to"]
chord.opts(fontscale=2, width=800, height=800, title='Collaborative Network')
chord.opts(
    opts.Chord(cmap='Category20', edge_cmap='Category20', edge_color=dim('to').str(), 
               labels='index', node_color=dim('index').str()))
```

[image: Chord diagram of countries network]

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved adding at the end of the code this: `chord.opts(label_text_font_size='12pt')`